# Math Snake Puzzle

Tags: puzzle

A colleague recently showed me the following puzzle game and I'm interested in how this can be solved. I thought it would be a good talking point for you guys as well :)

[image]

[A detailed description of the puzzle is here](http://www.creativecrafthouse.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=747).  A sequence of 7 cubes may be rotated about the axis.  The puzzle is to rotate them until all 4 equations are correct, such as $2 + 2 / 4 = 1$.  Operators are evaluated left to right.  The faces of the cube presented in the video (not agreeing with the image) are:

The following pictures show the sides...

[image: Side1]
[image: Side2]
[image: Side3]
[image: Side4]

> **Question**
>
> Other than trial and error, is there an easy way to solve this?

Comment: How do you prioritize operations?  Left to right, or multiplication first?  There is an easy answer, $1+1+1+1=4$, but to ask "how many solutions are there" is a more interesting question.

Comment: Each numeric cube has 4 options, 1 ,2, 3, 4. So if you use the number 1 on one side you cannot use it on another. The same applies with the operations.

Comment: Very similar to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_Insanity), but harder... interesting!

Comment: @DanielV: There aren't enough dice for $1+1+1+1=4$; but $1+1+1=3$ would work.

Comment: THere are far too many excedingly easy solutions to really consider this a puzzle.  It seems more useful as a device to set up a statement and to test yourself what if any solution there is, or an exercise it pattern making.  It *is* rather therapuetic the twist out 1+1+1=3;1+1+2=4;1+2+1=4;2+1+1=4 but it's hardly ... difficult.

Comment: 1+1+1=3 would work but what about the other sides? you need the other sides to evaluate as well!!!

Comment: Oh,  *all* sides simultaneously correct!  That is different!

Comment: We need to see what order the other sides are so we can rotate them.  From "away" rotation the first cube is 3,4,x,y which is different for the third or forth which are 4,3,a,b and 3,1,d,e etc.

Comment: This isn't solvable with the information we have, since we don't know the arrangements of the elements on each block. For instance, on the first two numeric ones, "4" and "3" are in opposite orders; and the last two numeric blocks show that the values aren't necessarily consecutive. (Looks like @fleablood and I had the same thought at the same time. :)

Comment: There are 6 possible way to arrange the numbers, op cubes (1,2,3,4 and 1,2,4,3 and 1,3,2,4 and 1,3,4,2 and 1,4,2,3 and 1,4,3,2) but only 3 and 2 of them are used.  We need to see what the other two sides of the snake are in order to solve this.

Comment: Shame on you! According to http://www.creativecrafthouse.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=747 you have given us the easy 7 block puzzle instead of the "very difficulty" 9 block model! :) There is a video on the site in which the snake is rotated for the eagle-eyed! The 7 block version has only 1 correct solution.

Comment: @blue you're right! Im so sorry I forgot to put that information on. I'll update the question as soon as I find out.

Comment: I think trial and error and common sense.  Don't want to divide by 3 unless you also multiply by 3 and I doubt there sides that fit that.  So that cut's our options down significantly...

Comment: Your picture doesn't agree with your ascii art.  I think your ascii art is wrong.

Comment: Yeah I spotted a mistake - Thank you. Updated

Comment: @fml Your last edit is incorrect, this version doesn't have a solution.  The one I left you with agrees with what is in the video.

Comment: The picture of the cubes and the table of the cube sides don't match. The third cube from left shows 4 followed by 3, but your table does not.

Answer (score 1):

The puzzle in the video only has 1 solution.

$$\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
4 & -      & 3 & \times & 3 & = & 3 \\
2 & +      & 2 & \div   & 4 & = & 1 \\
1 & \times & 4 & -      & 2 & = & 2 \\
3 & \div   & 1 & +      & 1 & = & 4 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

I doubt there is any significantly faster way to solve it than with a computer.  It's only $4^6 \div 4 = 1024$ cases to check.  I doubt there is a faster way than with a computer, since in general there can a large number of solutions.  This is a combinatorial logic problem, so it is NP, and I don't see any obvious way to put it into P.

Comment: Usually $4-3\times 3=-5$ and $2+2/4=2.5$

Comment: you changed the second operator sequence from $\times, -, +, \div$ to $\times, \div, -, +$.

Comment: @miracle173 I did not, the questioner changed it incorrectly.  The one I posted is correct according to the video linked.

Comment: on the website I found "The equation is read from left to right, irregardless of operation priority.", so you are right

Answer (score 0):

I just realised that I didn't get it, I just thought all the cubes had to show different numbers/symbols.

A solution that uses each number exactly once, and two different operations
$$
\frac{4}{2}+1=3
$$

I found that thinking about what divisions were possible. Obviously we can divide by one, but then we're just left with one operation ($+$, $-$ or $*$) on $\{2, 3, 4\}$, so 9 possibilities, it's not hard to check all of them and conclude that there are no solutions.

If we want the division to give an integer result the only other option is $\frac{4}{2}$, and that gives the solution I've already named.

If we just ignore a remainder from a a division, we get more solutions, like:
$$
\frac{4}{3}+1=2
$$

Comment: Apparently all four sides must match simultaneously.  And there's no restriction that each cube be used at most once in an equation.

Comment: Yes, I've realised that. Didn't get when I saw the question while on the train, and then thought about this during my walk from the station, and when I got home I didn't bother reading the new comments before typing up my answer.

Comment: Neither did I.  <><><><>